# Is there any short cuts for Xcode to tidy up the code?

Tags: xcode, editor, code-formatting, indentation

for example, I have something like this:

```
aVarible = 123; 
bIndex = 234; 
cSomethingVerylong = 456;
```

And I would like to intent the code like this:

```
aVarible           = 123; 
bIndex             = 234; 
cSomethingVerylong = 456;
```

How can I do so? Thank you.

Comment: Please don't do that, but if you must then that is what the space and/or tab keys are for.

Comment: Code indentation like this caused many compiler errors in the old days :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use uncrustify:

http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/

I don't use it, so I cannot vouch for its quality, but it does claim to do exactly what you suggest in your question. If that's *all* you want to do, it's probably overkill, but if you want to "tidy" your code in a number of ways, then that's what uncrustify is there for.