# Is there a tool to tidy up C++ code?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio

In Visual Studio there is a function (I guess it's shortcut was <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> followed by <kbd>D</kbd>) to automatically indent the code and clean up whitespace.

I'm now on Mac OS X doing C++ and like to have something similar. A CLI tool would be great. Is there something like this?

Comment: Please specify which editor you're using

Comment: I suggest to use QTcreator which is a cross platform C++ IDE, simple and clean. for more http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-indenting-code.html

Comment: Look at the following answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181560/is-there-any-short-cuts-for-xcode-to-tidy-up-the-code

You could use Uncrustify.

Comment: If you'd make your uncrustify comment an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) which is a CLI source code formatter for C, C++, C# and Java.